# Непрерывная моментальная работа с пользователем

Tags: javascript, websocket

Имеется websocket сервер, и страничный сайт, с обработкой websocket соединений через js.
Сейчас какое-либо действие реализуется следующим способом:
Приходит ответ с webscoket сервера клиентам, и у них выполняется определенная анимация (одна у всех). Если клиенту перезагрузить страницу, то он сразу получит конечный результат анимации.

Как сделать так, что бы при перезагрузки анимация оставалась на определенном шаге у пользователя?

Допустим, анимация - это выбор определенного пользователя из набора пользователей, вот идут прыжки по пользователям, и в итоге выберется какой-то один пользователь. Необходимо что бы при перезагрузке страницы анимация оставалась на определенном шаге, а не выдавался конечный выбранный пользователь.

Каким образом это можно реализовать? Прописывать каждый шаг анимации в websocket'е и отправлять его каждый раз всем пользователям?

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал использовать JS с сохранением времени начала анимации, смотрите первый [пример](https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation) с паравозиком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записывать шаги в локальное хранилище

Comment: Каждый шаг записывать в браузере допустим в куки, и потом просто проверять, если шаги не выполнены у пользователя, то делать данную анимацию?
А realtime вариантов реализации нету?

Comment: Что такое realtime? Один браузер выполнил анимацию за 10 секунд, второй за 15. Какой реалтайм?

Comment: Согласен. Спасибо за ответ.